# Pool maximum slope issues - ideas for workaround to have diving area

Tags: pool

Trying to figure out the design for a pool to have both a sports pool (ideally 3.5' - 4.5' deep where you can play volleyball) which also have a deep area for diving / jumping but have run into an issue with maximum grading.

The code here is at max a 10:1 slope if the water depth is less than 5 feet, and a 3:1 slope is only permitted if deeper than 5 feet, but that would either make the deep end too shallow or require too big of a pool or too deep for the sports area.

Does anyone have ideas for valid workarounds?  Wondering if perhaps rope floats or something could allow for a steeper grade or drop off. I know some is likely locality specific but curious of any ideas in general.

Comment: You need a broken measuring stick.

Comment: Don’t forget you’ll need a perimeter slotted drain around the perimeter of the pool or a built in perimeter drain that catches all the “bad” water and diverts it to the pool cleaning equipment. I’d talk to a pool installer. They can give idea of best type and cost.